# Integer Value in C Changing Each Execute

Tags: c

I'm attempting exercise 24 of chapter one in the K&R C Programming language book and I'm stuck on a certain bug. The exercise is to take a C program to find basic errors like unmatched braces or quotes, so what I've done is used counters to increase and decrease upon seeing a certain character in input, then printing those characters at the end. What I have happening though is two of these counters giving ridiculously large values (larger than the amount of characters in the input file itself) and furthermore changing each time I execute the code, on the same compile. Here's my code, the variables that are doing this are `singleQuote` and `escSequence`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define maxLine 1000
#define True 1
#define False 0

int main() {

    int c, i, braces, comments, escSequence, singleQuote, doubleQuote = 0;
    char input[maxLine];
    int insingleQuote, indoubleQuote = False;

    for (i=0; i<maxLine-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF; ++i) {
        input[i] = c;
    }
    input[i] = '\0';

    for (i=0; input[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (input[i] == '{') {
            ++braces;
        }
        if (input[i] == '}') {
            --braces;
        }
        if (input[i] == '\'' && insingleQuote == True) {
            insingleQuote = False;
            --singleQuote;
        }
        else if (input[i] == '\'') {
            insingleQuote = True;
            ++singleQuote;
        }
        if (input[i] == '\\' && insingleQuote == True && ((input[i+1] != 'n') || (input[i+1] != '\\') || (input[i+1] != '\'') || (input[i+1] != '\"') || (input[i+1] != 't') || (input[i+1] != 'b'))) {
            ++escSequence;
        }
        if (input[i] == '\"' && indoubleQuote == True) {
            indoubleQuote = False;
            --doubleQuote;
        }
        else if (input[i] == '\"') {
            indoubleQuote = True;
            ++doubleQuote;
        }
    }

printf("%s\n", input);
printf("Number of unmatched braces: %d\n", braces);
printf("Number of unmatched single quotes: %d\n", singleQuote);
printf("Number of unmatched double quotes %d\n", doubleQuote);
printf("Number of incorrect escape sequnces %d\n", escSequence);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only initialized `doubleQuote`, the rest are all uninitiialized -> *undefined behavior*

Comment: Oh wow, didn't realise that was incorrect syntax, though that explains it. Thanks.

Comment: it is not incorrect syntax. but you cannot know which value the variables hold, if you don't initialize them

Comment: regarding: `int insingleQuote, indoubleQuote = False;`  this leaves the variable: `insingleQuote` uninitialized.  Suggest: `int insingleQuote = 0; int indoubleQuote = 0;`

Comment: OT: you might want to look at the header file: `stdbool.h` for your boolean types, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int c, i, braces, comments, escSequence, singleQuote, doubleQuote = 0;
```

only doubleQuote is initialized to 0. the rest hold a random value, depending on where in memory they are and what was there before.

->undefined behaviour. initialize all values before you use them and your problem should be gone.